# Unable to create a specific Joda DateTime (IllegalInstantException)

Tags: java, jodatime

This very simple line:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0);
```

Crashes my application:

```
08-10 18:43:35.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
start activity (...): org.joda.time.IllegalInstantException: Illegal instant due 
to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 
2014-09-07T00:00:00.000  (America/Santiago)
```

I'm using Joda's DateTime for Java.

Question is: Should I create this DateTime with UTC datetime because apparently "this instant in time is impossible to exist"? how? if not, what's the solution?

As this question is so short, i will give a brief context:
I'm creating an array with all the days in a specific month/year, ie:

```
  Arr[0] = new SomeClass(....., new DateTime(2014, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0));
  Arr[1] = new SomeClass(....., new DateTime(2014, 9, 2, 0, 0, 0));
  Arr[2] = new SomeClass(....., new DateTime(2014, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0));
       ....
  Arr[6] = new SomeClass(....., new DateTime(2014, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0));
  Arr[7] = new SomeClass(....., new DateTime(2014, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0));
```

At 7 it crashes.

Comment: It's interesting that 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7' doesn't throw an exception in this case. I tried to change Time zones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to represent a "Date", which composed of Year + Month + Day Of Month, then there is a better choice in Joda.  Check for `LocalDate`.

This simply represent a date, instead of representing an instant in time.

Answer (score 3):

In Chile, DST ends on September 7th at midnight. So the time jumps from 23.59 to 01:00

Thats why midnight doesnt 'exist'.

As for solving it, you cant really. Anything that assumes that time exists is flawed.

Ref: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/chile/santiago

Comment: I see. What I want is to store day, year and month. I don't care about time (00:00:00 in this case). I thought storing these three in 3 variables inside "SomeClass" wouldn't be elegant....

Comment: How do I create the same DateTime without a zone? UTC